# From HTML to PHP, referencing

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website already in place with only html pages that all well referenced. I wanted to improve it and add some php.

But the page is now named index.php.

So I could use something like this in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [nc]
```

By doing this will I lose the referencing of my html pages by google ? Do I go back to the very begining ?

What will happen if people search for index.html ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

1. Say google to update it's data, I see that in wordpress exists option that say google when you and new page
2. Make in htaccsss possibility to find the same page with `.htm` and `.php`.
   Google with time may be correct the link in his search result to your site to `.html`.
3. Make and send new site map to google robot
4. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=ru.